# Create an instance of a custom generic class and a type stored in file as String

Tags: c#, reflection, activator

I am trying to create an instance of a generic class but my Type T of the generic class, i have gone through this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx
but i couldn't find what i was looking for

i have this code

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T prop { get; set; } 
}
```

and i have the type stored in string 
the type

```
string typeString = "System.String";
```

now i want to use this type in myclass this way

```
Type xt = new Type.GetType(typeString);
MyClass<xt> obj = new MyClass<xt>();
```

but that just unidentified type xt 
so what do i do!

Comment: Search MSDN for MakeGenericType.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The section *Constructing an Instance of a Generic Type* in the link provided covers this exact case.

In your case you would need write

```
Type typeArgument = Type.GetType(typestring);
Type constructed = typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(typeArgument);
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);
```

However, the use cases of this techniques are far from common. You should try as much as possible to *provide type information at compile-time*. That is, try not to rely on Reflection to create your objects. Generics methods are especially useful for such cases.

Comment: the problem now is that object is not useful and i don't which type to cast it to?

also object is no use i can't use prop property in myclass

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ? The fact that you load type information to be used at runtime from a text file looks a bit strange.
However, provided that you do need to instantiate the generic type at runtime, accessing its member later in the code requires either more Reflection (which is probably not what you want), or a cast to a parent type or to an interface. Yet, you need to know that at compile-time for the latter option.

Comment: yep i agree i need to store custom configurations, generically for an app, i need the fields to have a datatype

so my table has these fields Name, value, data type

i want to have my code make sure of the input type at run time natively

Comment: then again, the question comes back to can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

The method `Type.GetType(someString)` gets the type at runtime, but generics class must be evaluated at compiled time. Between the <> symbols you need to specify the type itself and not an instance of the object Type. Something like this must work:

```
MyClass<String> obj = new MyClass<String>();
```

Thanks,

Comment: that sounds like why i can't do it,
now do you have an article that says when the generic type is evaluated i mean like when you say at compile time

Comment: You can read more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx. In the compile time the compiler tries to resolve generic type usually represented by T.When you use Type.GetType, it means runtime. As Gabi mention you can instanciate a generic class in runtime, but only using Reflection.